# Receive mouse move even cursor is outside control

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I did something like scrollbar from `Control`. Everything is fine, but when cursor leaves control area, `OnMouseMove` is not received anymore.

When you use standard windows scrollbar, you can use it even if mouse cursor is outside the control's surface.

To avoid this, the only idea I have, is get cursor position from screen, then calculate scrollbar position on screen, and use timer or something to update my `Control`. But it sounds very hard and ugly.

Any idea how to fix it?

EDIT: I meant `Control` not `UserControl`.

EDIT2:
It receives mouse! I had bug in code, I called MouseDown in MouseMove method, but in MouseDown I had X/Y constraint that will force to return if X<0 etc.

Comment: Even this is solved, you will then encounters the same problem when cursor moves out from the scope of `Form`.

Comment: I think your problem is about the focus. The standard scroll bars only work when they have the focus.

Comment: @KenKin With the mouse capture (see my answer) you will get the movement even if it is outside the Window/Form

Comment: It's good. What I wanted to mention is, this is not only about controls but also forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `mouse capture` and is described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171545(v=vs.80).aspx

In short:

- on mouse down in your control you "capture" the mouse input
- then as long as no-one else captures the mouse, you will receive all mouse movement events, even those outside of your control
- you can release capture if you don't require the data anymore, optionally in "OnMouseUp"

Comment: Hmm I read it, and I still dont understand :/ What to do with this capture property?

Comment: @zgnilec: seem my update - basically you need to set that property `true` in your mouse down handling code